# what is c++ portable analog of c# AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent?

Tags: c++, boost

In c# I like very handy `AutoResetEvent` `ManualResetEvent` and `WaitHandle.WaitAll`.
What should I use in c++ (boost can be used) to have the same functionality? I need code to be portable so I can run it on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Might you be willing to describe what these things do?

Comment: I am not sure (I dont know c#), but you could use standard thread mechanisms, like semaphores.

Comment: @Omnifarious well probably this article can help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39040/Auto-and-Manual-Reset-Events-Revisited it's hard to explain in two words...

Comment: That does a fine job of explaining `AutoResetEvent` and `ManualResetEvent`, but does not explain `WaitHandle.WaitAll`, though I have a guess.

Comment: I can pass array of events to `WaitHandle.WaitAll` and then thread will be blocked until all events are set. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx There are also other methods, like `WaitHandle.WaitAny`.

Comment: @javapowered: As I suspected. There is no really portable way to do what you want to do. I think the ability to treat synchronization primitives as something you can wait on with a function like that would require a lot of infrastructure in C++. I'm actually working on that infrastructure in a library of my own. I would love to learn that my library is pointless to write.

Answer (score 1):

I have not read completely the link.I guess you could implement them using futures/promises.

The promises are used to set the event value, the future to wait for the value.

In order to get the auto/manual reset you will need an additional indirection using a smart pointer so that the promise/future are re-allocated.

Next follows the idea:

```
template <typename T>
class AutoResetEvent 
{
  struct Impl {
    promise<T> p;
    future<T> f;
    Impl(): p(), f(p) {}
  };
  scoped_ptr<Impl> ptr;
public:
  AutoResetEvent() : ptr(new Impl()) {}
  set_value(T const v) {
    ptr->p.set_value(v);
  }
  T get() {
     T res = ptr->f.get();
     ptr.reset(new Impl());
  }
  void wait() {
     ptr->f.wait();
     ptr.reset(new Impl());
  }
};
```

You will need a little bit more to make them movable.

Waiting on several futures consist just in iterating on a container of the events you want to wait for.